# Redirecting multiline output to multiple files

Tags: bash, awk

I have a list of URLs, and would like to identify what is a directory and what is not:

```
https://www.example.com/folder/
https://www.example.com/folder9/
https://www.example.com/folder/file.sh
https://www.example.com/folder/text
```

I can use `grep -e /$` to find which is which, but I'd like to do an inline command where I can redirect the output based on that logic.

I understand that awk may have the answer here, but don't have enough experience in awk to do this.

Something like:

```
cat urls | if /$ matches write to folders.txt else write to files.txt
```

I could drop it all to a file then read it twice but when it gets to thousands of lines I feel that would be inefficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `awk` is a great choice for this:

```
awk '/\/$/ { print > "folders.txt"; next }
           { print > "files.txt" }' urls.txt
```

- `/\/$/ { print > "folders.txt"; next }` if the line ends with a /, write it to folders.txt and skip to the next line
- `{ print > "files.txt" }` write all other lines to files.txt

You may want to use the expression `/\/[[:space:]]*$/` instead of `/\/$/` in case you have trailing spaces in your file.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is:

```
awk '{print > ((/\/$/ ? "folders" : "files")".txt")}' urls.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

With coreutils, grep and bash process substitution:

```
<urls tee >(grep '/$' > folders.txt) >(grep -v '/$' > files.txt) > /dev/null
```