# Extract data and save in different output files

Tags: bash, awk

I have a data file with the following format:

```
aaa     0
bbb     1
ccc     2
ddd     ?
eee     0
fff     1
ggg     2
hhh     3
iii     ?
   ...
```

What I want to do is quite simple: extract and save the parts of the data in different files with the criteria for splitting being only taking the lines between 0 and the '?' so that I would obtain:

output_1.txt >

```
aaa     0
bbb     1
ccc     2
ddd     ?
```

output_2.txt >

```
eee     0
fff     1
ggg     2
hhh     3
iii     ?
```

And so on until the end of the input file is reached.
I've tried to look into awk command but I'm not quite sure how to specify the conditions nor how to create an output file that depends on the number of times the data is split.

Comment: Related: [Redirecting multiline output to multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51794902/6862601).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is:

```
awk 'NR==1 || $NF=="?"{close(out); out="output_"++cnt".txt"} {print > out}' file
```

The above will work with any awk in any shell on any UNIX system for any size of input file.

If you wanted to do a partial match on `?` (see the comments below) then it'd be either of these:

```
awk 'NR==1 || index($NF,"?"){close(out); out="output_"++cnt".txt"} {print > out}' file

awk 'NR==1 || $NF~/\?/{close(out); out="output_"++cnt".txt"} {print > out}' file

awk 'NR==1 || $NF~/[?]/{close(out); out="output_"++cnt".txt"} {print > out}' file
```

Comment: I am not looking for the expression to match exactly "?" but rather to be approximate. I tried to replace $NF=="?" by $NF~"?" but it didn't like the ~. Any way to give an approximate expression?

Comment: Yes but that's not necessary given the sample input you posted so what's the point? I added some ways to do it anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much Ed, I really appreciate :) In my example, you are right, I only need equal sign. But in the actual data, we have sometime ?1 or ?2, hence the need for a ~. I will try what you propose and I think it should be fine. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. Going forward please just make your sample input as much like your real input as possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can redirect print statements in awk:

```
awk -v n=1 '{print > ("output_" n ".txt")} $2 == "?" {n++}' file
```

If your file is large, you may have to explicitly close the open file:

```
awk -v n=1 '
    {print > ("output_" n ".txt")} 
    $2 == "?" {close("output_" n ".txt"); n++}
' file
```

---

If I was feeling really DRY, I would write

```
awk -v n=1 '
    function filename(n) {return "output_" n ".txt"} 
    {print > filename(n)} 
    $2 == "?" {close(filename(n++))}  # important, post-increment
' file
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working exactly like I hoped. I'll have a closer look at this command to make sure I understand the process :)

Comment: You'll want to read [Redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html#Redirection) in the gawk manual