# MAC OS Awk - Syntax error when generating files with a variable

Tags: macos, awk

The following command takes the file *temp_practice.txt* and split it into several files *temp_output_1.txt, temp_output_2.txt, etc...* based on the criteria **$5~"?"**

> awk -v n=1 '{print > "temp_output_" n ".txt"} $5~"?" {n++}' temp_practice.txt

On Ubuntu, it works very smoothly and I get exactly what I want. However, when I try to run the same command on Mac, I get the following syntax error:

```
awk: syntax error at source line 1
context is
{print > "temp_output_" >>>  n <<<  ".txt"} $5~"?" {n++}
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
```

There seems to be a syntax error with the n variable that generates the name of the file. I know that there are differences between awk on Linux and on Mac but I cannot find any information about that particular problem. Do I need to use a different command or do I simply need to add something to the existing line?

Comment: Could you please try changing `"temp_output_" n ".txt"` to `("temp_output_" n ".txt")` once? Though I haven't have mac with me so haven't tested this.

Comment: Tried and it seems to be working as the error is now shifted to the next bracket:

{print > ("temp_output_" n ".txt")} $5~"?" >>>  { <<<

Comment: Try changing `$5~"?" {n++}` to `($5~"?"){n++}` too once and let me know then?

Comment: So running 
awk -v n=1 '{print > ("temp_output_" n ".txt")} ($5~"?") {n++}' temp_practice.txt
gives me
>awk: illegal primary in regular expression ? at 
 source line number 1
 context is
 {print > ("temp_output_" n ".txt")} >>>  ($5~"?") <<<

Comment: try changing `$5~/?/` once and let me know then?

Comment: It keeps giving me an error that is about $5~? but when I just leave that part as it is, it shows no error. Instead, the error appears on the next brackect: **{print > ("temp_output_" n ".txt")} $5~"?" >>> { <<<** see the arrows pointing to it.

Comment: Go back to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52767896/7552) and use Ed Morton's answer. Some older awk implementations don't like an *expression* on the right-hand side of the redirection arrow: need either a plain variable or a fixed string.

Comment: @glennjackman it's nothing to do with older/newer awks and having an expression there is fine but it's got to be within parens or it's undefined behavior per POSIX and so different awks will behave differently. Just always use `getline < (foo bar)` and `print > (foo bar)`, never `getline < foo bar` or `print > foo bar` for portability.

Answer (score 0):

[I told you about this exact issue previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52767896/extract-data-and-save-in-different-output-files/52768484?noredirect=1#comment92467049_52768484). Your next issue is unrelated to the one your question is about. `?` is a regexp metachar meaning `zero-or-one repetitions of the preceding expression` but look at your regexp `/?/` - you don't HAVE a preceding expression. So some awks might treat `?` as literal and others might produce a syntax error. To match a literal `?`, which I assume is what you're trying to do, is `$5~/\?/` or `$5~/[?]/` or `index($5,"?")` or maybe even `$5=="?"` depending on your input and requirements.

Comment: Thank you Ed. For some reason, I had missed your answer on my other issue. I will look into both thread and see if I can manage to work it out.

Comment: Hi Ed. It seems to be solving the initial issue but now, it requires me to close all the files I have opened before it can continue to create more of them. I know there is the command close() but everything I tried didn't work. Here is what I have for now: **awk -v n=1 '{print > ("temp_output_" n ".txt")} $5~/\?/ {n++}' temp_practice.txt**

Comment: That is not following the style I showed in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52772620/1745001). Just do what I showed you. wrt `it requires me to close all the files I have opened before it can continue to create more of them` - yes, that's the point, you have to do that or you end up with too many open files.